# Clickable external link to ssh URL in MediaWiki pages

Tags: macos, ssh, mediawiki

I use mediawiki internally for our lab inventory purposes. I have a bunch of linux boxes I would like to provide a link to within the page for our users to click on and open an SSH session instead of manually typing ssh user@hostname. I would like to provide a hyperlink so that when someone clicks on the link, the default ssh client (in a mac - terminal) will open up and all the user needs to do is enter the password and hit enter.

Can someone please help? i have tried ssh://user@hostname with and without the square brackets and it does not help. with the square brackets, mediawiki opens a new page with the title ssh://user@hostname, but does not open an ssh session.

Comment: It's not MediaWiki that opens a new page, it's your browser. How different browsers and operating systems handle url's is entirely up to them.

Comment: I think you have to register the protocol ssh so that it opens the ssh client. I have no idea how is that done in mac.

Answer (score 0):

From Firefox, install the [Firessh](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firessh/) addon and on media wiki create a link ssh://user@server

Comment: thanks but that does not work, it still opens another page with the title

Comment: @raj.andy1, is ssh in your [$wgUrlProtocols](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUrlProtocols)?